# How to call Google Tasks API from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I amtrying to call Google Tasks API for a app I'm building.When I make the call using Google's client libraries, it succeeds and return what is expected.

```
function getAllTasks() {
gapi.client.tasks.tasks.list({
    tasklist: 'MDIxODc1MzEwNzc4MzMxNDU2MTU6MDow'
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    var arr = response.result.items;
    console.log(arr);
    for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
        console.log(arr[j].title);
    }
})
}
```

But when I do the same using jQuery, I get 404 with the text "Login Requied" in the response body.

```
function getAllTasksJquery() {
$.get("https://content.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/MDIxODc1MzEwNzc4MzMxNDU2MTU6MDow/tasks",function (data,status) {
    console.log(data,status);
    var arr = data.result.items;
    console.log(arr);
    for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++) {
        console.log(arr[j].title);
    }
});

}
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after hours of search, I finally figured this out. Since I was using the Google's JS Client libraries, I almost ignored the fact that I have to pass my oauth2 `access_token` with each API call. Only then will the API know the account to access.
More specifically, pass the `access_token` in the header while making API requests. Here is a jQuery snippet for the same :

```
$.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists`,{access_token: AccessToken}, function (data,status) {
    console.log(status,data);
});
```

Hope it helps the others...